# adding two columns together to get a sum from a union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
 with abby as (SELECT u.Name as 'UserId1'
, count(distinct b.id) as 'Total Count'
, '' as 'ediCount'

FROM abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Batch] b with(nolock)

inner join abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Principal] u with(nolock) on u.Id = b.CreatorId

where b.CreationDate >= getdate() - 7 
and u.name <> 'abbyyservice'

group by u.Name)

,  edimon as (select userId
, '' as 'Total Count'
, count(*) as 'esubCount'

from ESubmitTrackingTBL

where DateCopied >= getdate() - 7
    and userid <> abbyyservice

group by UserId
)

select * from abby union all select * from edimon
```

I need to sum the totals from each cte into another field by user.  I have tried to include another cte but get a warning that 'UserID' and 'Total Count' are specified more than once.
If I just run the query as unions, the result is shown below:
[image]

End result should look like the following:

[image]

If I have left anything out that may help, my apologies -- please let me know what I can add to clarify this if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd dispense with the CTEs and just use a derived table.

To avoid problems when query or stored procedure executions cross date boundaries, I prefer to use T-SQL variables and establish a consistent sense of *Now-ness* for the entire run. Crossing a midnight boundary and having "today" change in mid-run can cause ... subtle problems, if you're not careful about things. Don't ask me how I know this.

So...

```
declare @now         datetime = current_timestamp      -- current instant in time
declare @today       date     = @now                   -- today's date
declare @cutoff_date date     = dateadd(day,-7,@today) -- 1 week ago
```

Your `cutoff_date` value might vary depending on whether your spec requires looking at the previous 7 *calendar days* or the previous 168 hours (7*24) relative to the current moment in time).

So my query would then look something like this:

```
declare @now         datetime = current_timestamp      -- current instant in time
declare @today       date     = @now                   -- today's date
declare @cutoff_date date     = dateadd(day,-7,@today) -- 1 week ago

select user_id        =      x.user_id       ,
       total_count    = sum( x.total_count ) ,
       edi_count      = sum( x.edi_count   ) ,
       grand_total    = sum( x.total_count )
                      + sum( x.edi_count   ) ,
       esub_count_pct = 100.0
                      * sum( x.edi_count )
                      / (   sum( x.total_count )
                          + sum( x.edi_count   )
                        )
from (   select user_id     = u.Name ,
                total_count = count( distinct b.id ) ,
                esub_count  = 0
         from abprot.FC10y.dbo.Batch     b
         join abprot.FC10y.dbo.Principal u on u.Id   =  b.Creator.Id
                                          and u.name <> 'abbyyservice'
         where b.CreationDate >= @cutoff_date
         group by u.Name
       UNION ALL
         select user_id     = t.userId ,
                total_count = 0        ,
                esub_count  = 1
         from dbo.ESubmitTrackingTBL t
         where t.DateCopied >= @cutoff_date
     ) x
group by x.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query did look chopped off.  I assume that you just want what is in the last CTE.

The calculation is pretty simple.  I'm a bit surprised that someone who could put together this SQL wouldn't figure out the final calculation:

```
with abby as (
      SELECT u.Name as UserId, count(distinct b.id) as [Total Count], '' as ediCount
      FROM abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Batch] b with(nolock) inner join
           abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Principal] u with(nolock)
           on u.Id = b.CreatorId
      where b.CreationDate >= getdate() - 7 and u.name <> 'abbyyservice'
      group by u.Name
    ), 
    edimon as (
     select userId, '' as [Total Count], count(*) as esubCount
     from ESubmitTrackingTBL
     where DateCopied >= getdate() - 7 and userid <> abbyyservice
    )
select userId, [Total Count], esubcount,  ([Total Count] + esubcount) as Total,
       100.0 * esubcount / ([Total Count] + esubcount) as [percent edisubcount] 
from edimon;
```

A word of advice:  avoid using single quotes for identifiers.  It is preferable to use names (such as `userid`) that do not need to be escaped.  If you do, then use square braces.

EDIT:

Your problem is probably easier than you are making it out to be.  Try using `group by with rollup`:

```
SELECT u.Name as UserId, count(distinct b.id) as [Total Count], '' as ediCount,
        ([Total Count] + esubcount) as Total,
       100.0 * esubcount / ([Total Count] + esubcount) as [percent edisubcount] 
FROM abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Batch] b with(nolock) inner join
     abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Principal] u with(nolock)
     on u.Id = b.CreatorId
where b.CreationDate >= getdate() - 7 and u.name <> 'abbyyservice'
group by u.Name with rollup;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff.  I appreciate the assistance.  When I ran what you provided, and review the results, I am missing one row from what I get when I run it just as a UNION query (without the totals and percentages.  This record would come from the abby CTE, rather than the edimon cte.  That record needs to be in the final results.

Answer (score 0):

```
with abby as (
      SELECT u.Name as UserId, count(distinct b.id) as [Total Count], '' as ediCount
      FROM abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Batch] b with(nolock) inner join
           abprot.[FC10y].[dbo].[Principal] u with(nolock)
           on u.Id = b.CreatorId
      where b.CreationDate >= getdate() - 7 and u.name <> 'abbyyservice'
      group by u.Name
    ), 
    edimon as (
     select userId, '' as [Total Count], count(*) as esubCount
     from ESubmitTrackingTBL
     where DateCopied >= getdate() - 7 and userid <> 'abbyyservice'
    )

select UserId, 
  TotalCount, 
  esubCount, 
  convert(decimal, esubCount)/(convert(decimal, TotalCount) + convert(decimal, esubCount)) percentesubCount
from (select * from abby
      union
      select * from edimon) x
```